# com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I'm using ibm cloud MQ and trying to retrieve message from queue. I checked all the properties including queue manager name, queue name, username, password, channel, port and host as well, everything looks correct. But still I'm facing this issue.

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for queue manager 'xxx' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'xxxx(yyyy)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the queue manager to which you are connecting.  For further information, review the queue manager error logs and the Securing IBM MQ topic within IBM Knowledge Center. 
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:450)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:8475)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7815)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl._createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:322)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:242)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6026)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:111)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:200)
    at com.ibm.wce.scbn.api2api.api2apijobs.service.MQMessageChecker.init(MQMessageChecker.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.ibm.wce.scbn.api2api.api2apijobs.Api2apiJobsApplication.main(Api2apiJobsApplication.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:203)
    ... 39 more
```

Java Code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.CommonConstants;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.jms.*;

@Component
public class MQMessageChecker {
    
    private final String queueName;
    private Connection connection;
    private Session session;

    @Autowired
    public MQMessageChecker() {
        this.queueName = "xxx";
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
            connectionFactory.setHostName("xxxx");
            connectionFactory.setPort(32607);
            connectionFactory.setQueueManager("xxxx");
            connectionFactory.setChannel("xxxx");
            connectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, "config");
            connectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, "xxxxx");
            connectionFactory.setIntProperty(CommonConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            System.out.println("Connection: " + connection);
            System.out.println("Session: " + session);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000) // Run every minute
    public void checkMQForMessages() {
        try {
            if (connection == null || session == null) {
                System.out.println("enetring inside null condition");
                init();
            }
            System.out.println("Session: " + session );
            System.out.println("queueName: " + queueName );
            Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);

            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue, "timestamp <= " + System.currentTimeMillis());

            connection.start();
            Message message;
            while ((message = consumer.receive()) != null) {
                if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                    System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " processing message " + textMessage.getText());
                    System.out.println("Received Text Message: " + textMessage.getText());
                }
            }
            consumer.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

This is the dependency I used in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
  <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Also tried this dependency as well both results in same error.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does the user has the authority to connect to queue manager?

Comment: This looks like insufficient app permissions to access the queue manager / channel / queue.

Comment: yes, user has access to connect to queue manager

Comment: What is logged in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG? Did this work in the past?  Did you just upgrade to 9 3 jar files?  If you did just upgrade what version did you have when it worked?

Comment: Please update your question with the errors shown in the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG file at the time of failure.

Comment: @vijay did you solved the problem ? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Yes, I'm directly started using MQ properties from application.properties file without initializing. And instead 'MQQueueConnectionFactory' use 'JmsTemplate'.